# Not able to upgrade civicrm from 5.33 to 5.60

Tags: php

I'm trying to upgrade civicrm from 5.33 to 5.60 and facing below issue and not able to go forward. Any help is much appreciated

```
[Error: Finish core DB updates 5.60.0]
CRM_Core_Exception: Parameter "where" is required unless primary keys are supplied in values. in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php on line 72
```

I was not able to check which table is causing this issue or where to amend the code to move on.

Comment: I have seldom had much luck repairing issues when an upgrade fails. I would suggest that you return to your backup, review the site for odd behaviours and address them before an upgrade. When you have tackled the working install, you can then try the upgrade again. I would also suggest that you try upgrading in smaller steps. I have found that helpful sometimes.

Comment: I managed to resolve it by adding missing columns in respective tables which I found it from log file. Just gave a try and it worked :)

Comment: @SrinivasNarula i'm facing the same error upgrading from 5.53 to 5.54 and is not able to locate useful logs pointing to missing columns. Can you point me to where the logs might be located, or what are the columns that you found missing?